# How to use React.FC<props> type when the children can either be a React node or a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have this sample component

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode, useMemo } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

type Props = {
  children: ((x: number) => ReactNode) | ReactNode;
};

const Comp: FC<Props> = function Comp(props) {
  const val = useMemo(() => {
    return 1;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {typeof props.children === "function"
        ? props.children(val)
        : props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

Comp.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.func]).isRequired
};

export default Comp;
```

My intent here is that the `children` prop of the component can either be

- a `node`, which is described as

  > Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array (or fragment) containing these types.
- a `function`, (or a "render prop") which simply gets a value from inside the component and returns another `node`

the point here is to be explicit, that the `children` can either be the one (`node`, which is pretty much everything) or the other (which is simply a `function`)

## The problem

I am facing the following issues however with the type check.

- if I leave the code as presented here, I get the following error message on the line `? props.children(val)`

  > This expression is not callable.
  >   Not all constituents of type 'Function | ((x: number) => ReactNode) | (string & {}) | (number & {}) | (false & {}) | (true & {}) | ({} & string) | ({} & number) | ({} & false) | ({} & true) | (((x: number) => ReactNode) & string)

I do not understand this error.

- if I change the `Props` type to be

```
type Props = {
  children: (x: number) => ReactNode;
};
```

and rely on React's own `type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };` to handle the case where `children` is not a function, then I get the error

> (property) children?: PropTypes.Validator<(x: number) => React.ReactNode>
>   Type 'Validator' is not assignable to type 'Validator<(x: number) => ReactNode>'.
>     Type 'ReactNodeLike' is not assignable to type '(x: number) => ReactNode'.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(x: number) => ReactNode'.ts(2322)
>   Comp.tsx(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type

on the line `children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.func]).isRequired`

The only solution is to leave the `Props` type as

```
type Props = {
  children: (x: number) => ReactNode;
};
```

and also change the `Comp.propTypes` to be `children: PropTypes.func.isRequired`, which is *not* what I want, since I want to be explicit.

## The question

How can I keep the code explicit, as presented at the start of this question, and also not have the type checking throw errors on me?

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-kalam-qo1t9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tldr:

The [`React.FC`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9bdc01d75d8e9d3fb651a63b9e94547a01b228ad/types/react/index.d.ts#L515-L523) type is the cause for [above error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=8&ssc=13&pln=8&pc=22#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtsujAHIQAmS2ArgM5ICySIEcAvnAGZQQg4AIiioMQgNwBYAFChIsOAAV+YACoBPMEga9+goWFUBaGFp2TZss9uWrdAXlyy4cNAAtgAGyqiAdgBccAAUwQAeQX50IABGSFAAlHAOAHyIYhTUSEkAPulklDTSMpzFsmgQfgzwhAJgQUQAPCoQYAxpTjx0fhjAlXC14MFGrQxJOC5uldVwAG4oXslwjCxsEKFJqc4yrq6iMHRQfnAAjMWunNgA2gC6CWU7cPuHx8GTro1UwLMp77s4NiQEB4cBGbQAdB5vL4kMcHPDhF0ejA+n4hH9dnAAPyg+yQzw+fzBeZeBIY3ZBMEMfHQ-ycP6NAD0Xx+k3uslKVhkgzA4LBmm0jm2rihhNhQRa6nM1MqSAA8jwBUhgldJUrqX4stg1dLwUi0HdwcAGMgAI50YCiKgch5IMIKeA0HgoOheGp1CRAA):

1. It already includes default [`children`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9bdc01d75d8e9d3fb651a63b9e94547a01b228ad/types/react/index.d.ts#L773) typed as [`ReactNode`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9bdc01d75d8e9d3fb651a63b9e94547a01b228ad/types/react/index.d.ts#L202), which get merged (`&`) with your own `children` type contained in `Props`.
2. `ReactNode` is a [fairly wide type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9bdc01d75d8e9d3fb651a63b9e94547a01b228ad/types/react/index.d.ts#L201) limiting the compiler's ability to narrow down the `children` union type to a callable function in combination with point 1.

A solution is to omit `FC` and use a more narrow type than `ReactNode` to benefit type safety:

```
type Renderable = number | string | ReactElement | Renderable[]
type Props = {
  children: ((x: number) => Renderable) | Renderable;
};
```

---

## More details

First of all, here are the built-in React types:

```js
type ReactText = string | number;
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;

interface ReactNodeArray extends Array<ReactNode> {}
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean 
  | null | undefined;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
  displayName?: string;
}

type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };
```

1.) You use `FC<Props>` to type `Comp`. `FC` internally *already* includes a `children` declaration typed as `ReactNode`, which gets merged with `children` definition from `Props`:

```
type Props = { children: ((x: number) => ReactNode) | ReactNode } & 
  { children?: ReactNode }
// this is how the actual/effective props rather look like
```

2.) Looking at `ReactNode` type, you'll see that types get considerably more complex. `ReactNode` includes type `{}` via `ReactFragment`, which is the **supertype of everything except `null` and `undefined`**. I don't know the exact decisions behind this type shape, [microsoft/TypeScript#21699](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699) hints at historical and backward-compatiblity reasons.

As a consequence, `children` types are wider than intended. This causes your original errors: type guard `typeof props.children === "function"` cannot narrow the type "muddle" properly to `function` anymore.

### Solutions

#### Omit `React.FC`

In the end, `React.FC` is just a function type with extra properties like `propTypes`, `displayName` etc. with opinionated, wide `children` type. Omitting `FC` here will result in safer, more understandable types for compiler and IDE display. If I take your definition `Anything that can be rendered` for `children`, that could be:

```
import React, { ReactChild } from "react";
// You could keep `ReactNode`, though we can do better with more narrow types
type Renderable = ReactChild | Renderable[]

type Props = {
  children: ((x: number) => Renderable) | Renderable;
};

const Comp = (props: Props) => {...} // leave out `FC` type
```

#### Custom `FC` type without `children`

You could define your own `FC` version, that contains everything from `React.FC` except those wide `children` types:

```
type FC_NoChildren<P = {}> = { [K in keyof FC<P>]: FC<P>[K] } & // propTypes etc.
{ (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement | null } // changed call signature

const Comp: FC_NoChildren<Props> = props => ...
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtgK4DOSAskiBNsujIQBbAA2AJvahgKJs0kAO3gBfOADMoEEHABEUHjDkBuALAAoUJFhwACtLAAVAJ5gkZSdNlywhgLQwzF1Zs1PziYRyRQUAIwE4AF4vRhZ2DjgAHy8hHz9ApABtAF03DQ8kfUNLUJxNODg0Vk5FIQAuOAAKaoAPKqESEH9fAEoQgD44hICBDtjkeN8%20pHUNUXHNNAghMnhCGTAQyRIhDGBZuEXwarsIMDIqgwOyDoKNIpm5%20AA3FDYV8ioaCFqO4O6LoqLFGBIoEI4ABGcZFUTYNJtKaXOB-AFA6qFH4AHg4wFunWRP1wWQgEjg%200OADoSpFyiFgqE5BI1htZnJsTi4AB%20Qm5UmlDjlar3NhtJk4qpEsic8nCURMlEAenRmOR0M0kwyOzAxKJpnMeVwyLJZWEx0MmosxNmSAA8hJjdVkidjM5RUIID5sHbjaLaetUm1icAyMgAI4kYCKDhKmFZAiEAD6ADkIBF9UIUXoVjhRN18nBkgBpODAIEAayQJnxUZTnVSVSIFdzqTg4gAZHBpdL2Qd3XAkDA0MTNHg9rljthrjAkHUYCyqighCY2lUGHwBCBhPBYk02I9xK3ig9HmRgABzIQof6KDLXebbJYAJmrMfjie5whTuUz7cOXTgaIxWNhODxAkRTFJNKWpT16SERlYSKNlgL1Z8hGqAAWG8BRguBhQ5BDyklDQZTlP8gA)

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you. If you want to know more about how I solved my issue check my updated answer (which I should have already updated 2 days ago). I have good reason (imo) why I still hold on to `propTypes` :D

Answer (score 1):

I think that global union might help:

```
type Props = {
  children: ((x: number) => ReactNode);
} | {
  children: ReactNode;
};
```

Comment: This works, but I do not understand why this works while `type Props = { children: ((x: number) => ReactNode) | ReactNode;};` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which works, and doesn't require to write the `Props` declaration any differently or rewrite anything else differently, is to *strictly* define the type of the `props` parameter, during the component definition, like this

```
type Props = {
  children: ((x: number) => ReactNode) | ReactNode;
};

const Comp: FC<Props> = function Comp(props: Props) { // we strictly define the props type here
  ...
}

Comp.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.func]).isRequired
};
```

I am not 100% sure why this makes a difference, my intuition is that we "force" our own `Props` definition down to the type checker, so we limit the possible scope.

## UPDATE

Ever since I asked the original question I eventually settled for the following solution to my problem: **I defined my own function component type**:

```
//global.d.ts

declare module 'react' {
  // Do not arbitrarily pass children down to props.
  // Do not type check actual propTypes because they cannot always map 1:1 with TS types,
  // forcing you to go with PropTypes.any very often, in order for the TS compiler
  // to shut up

  type CFC<P = {}> = CustomFunctionComponent<P>;

  interface CustomFunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
    propTypes?: { [key: string]: any };
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
  }
}
```

This solution

- Allows me to strictly define what is a function component
- Does not force any arbitrary `children` prop into my definition
- Does not cross reference any actual `Component.propTypes` with the TS `type Props = {...}`. Many times they would not map exactly 1:1, and I was forced to use `PropTypes.any` which is not what I wanted.

The reason I am keeping the `Component.propTypes` along with the TS types, is that while TS is very nice during development, `PropTypes` will actually warn in case of a wrong-type value during runtime, which is useful behaviour when, for example, a field in an API response was supposed to be a number and is now a string. Things like this may happen and it's not something TS can help with.

### Further Reading

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34237
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34237#issuecomment-486374424

Comment: can you explain how you use this?

Comment: Sure, what would you like to know? Be a little more specific

Comment: oh, where did you put it (global.d.ts?), is that in the root dir? and an example of how you use it in your code, that is what i meant.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I put it in the global.d.ts, exactly as shown here. The usage is nothing special, you just use `React.FC` as usual, but now the `children` prop is not implicitly passed down. As a disclaimer though, I have moved away from `React.FC` altogether, and I just declare the components as simple functions like `function Component(props: Props) { .... }`

Comment: Why have you moved away from React.FC?

Comment: Because I find it simpler to not have to worry about React.FC and also I prefer to write my components as functions instead of constants